# The inverse of a complex function

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

$f: \Bbb C \to U(0,1)$={$z \in \Bbb C; |z|<1$}

$f(z)=\frac{z}{1+|z|} $

I have found it is bijective, but how can I find $f^{-1}$?
I wrote z = $\frac{u}{1+|u|}$ and tried to write u depending on z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

What are the relationships between the magnitudes and arguments of $z$ and $u$?

Comment: I did some calculation and got that $|u| $= $\frac{|z|}{1-|z|} $, so $u = z(1+ $ $\frac{|z|}{1-|z|}) $. So $f^{-1}(z)$ = $z(1+ $ $\frac{|z|}{1-|z|}$) ?

Comment: Not quite.  The conditions (i) $\arg(z)=\arg(u)$ and (ii) $|u|=\frac{|z|}{1-|z|}$ imply that $$u=\frac{z}{1-|z|}$$.